# How to have the device user location using folium based on GPS?

Tags: python, gps, folium

I have a Python project using folium. I would like the sintax with its code on how to have the device/user GPS location on my map with the icon when I click it zoom to the point.

Answer (score 0):

This method should help you:

```
from folium.plugins import LocateControl
```

Important! folium version should be upgraded.
The documentation is [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium-plugins).

Comment: How to save it to a variable?